# QBasic crashes immediately after selecting the "open" menu item

Tags: ide, qbasic, ntvdm

Not sure if this is even an acceptable question, but I figured it's an IDE so...

I'm trying to write a small program in qb4.5, which has happily worked on my computer (XP SP3) for a while now.  For some reason though it is now sluggish and error-prone.  As the title reads, if I try to open a file then QB crashes out.  A virus recently attacked my registry (among other things), and after removing it and fixing many entries there are probably some entries that I haven't corrected that may affect this.

Comment: Would be good to make this into an actual question, although my intentions are obvious.  How can I fix this?

Comment: That's neat that you're using QBasic.  I'm curious what kinds of programs you're writing for such an old platform.

Comment: First mistake: You failed to format your drive and reinstall Windows after suffering from a virus attack. Sure, it's one thing to go in and try to clean things up so that you can recover your files and do a backup. But there's just no excuse for trying to continue running on a compromised OS installation whose registry you've admittedly had to hack on yourself. Wipe your drive, reinstall Windows and all of your programs, then check back with us. Your problem (and a whole bunch of others) are almost guaranteed to magically disappear.

Comment: Well, I suppose there's not much I can do but agree with you on this...Darned quiet nagging voice of reason.  Probably for the best.

@Jacob: I've made all sorts of things from tiny to medium size, the later ones having their own GUIs.  Right now I just want to write a custom timer with a ten second preparation time before the actual timer starts with system beeps to indicate start and stop.  In the meantime though I've moved larger projects to C#.

Comment: I'm not really all that quiet, but I'll sure take the "voice of reason" compliment. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that QuickBasic uses the MSDOS edit command for its IDE. Presumable that program is affected by the virus. If that is the case, you should have problems opening other files in EDIT too.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe that QuickBasic uses the MSDOS edit command for its IDE

The QuickBASIC IDE (-> `QB.EXE`) is a self-contained application. QuickBASIC doesn't use the MS DOS editor (`EDIT.COM`) as an input screen. The QB IDE offers several features you won't find in `EDIT.COM`, for example a SUB/FUNCTION browser, live syntax checking, compile+launch menu, ...

The styling of the QB IDE looks very similar to the appearance of `EDIT.COM` but it's a different application. In fact, one can run QB.EXE in DOSBOX without even having EDIT.COM installed.